# Ion CheckRadio click events

Tags: jquery

how to write jquery Ion.CheckRadio 1.0.2 jQuery plugin for styling checkboxes and radio-buttons button onclick events.

```
<pre>
    <input type="radio" name="reading" value="0" id="reading_0" /> <label for="reading_0">Very much</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reading" value="1" id="reading_1" /> <label for="reading_1">Sometimes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reading" value="2" id="reading_2" /> <label for="reading_2">Better watch movie</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reading" value="3" id="reading_3" /> <label for="reading_3">Hate it</label>

    or that way:

    <label><input type="radio" name="movies" value="0" /> Love them</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="movies" value="1" /> Like them</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="movies" value="2" /> Indifferent</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="movies" value="3" /> Hate it</label>

    or drop some checkboxes:

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="think" value="0" /> Work</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="think" value="1" checked /> Rest</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="think" value="2" disabled checked /> Sex</label>
</pre>
```

how to write checkbox click event??
i tried ordinary checkbox click event but its not supporting

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the "click" event bind to the "change" event. Example uses jquery 1.10.2 and ion.checkRadio.js 1.1.0. The weird thing is this example shows "true" correctly the first time the box is checked, but after that it shows "false" regardless of checked state.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[name='mygroup']").change(function () {
            alert($(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });
</script>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1" name="mygroup" />Orange</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox2" name="mygroup" />Red</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="radio_class" data-value="0">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="think" value="0" /> Work
    </label>
</a>
```

Its better to use a tag over the radio button.

```js
$(".radio_class").click(function(){
  radio_selected_value = $(this).attr("data-value");
});
```